# RQT_GUI fails after upgrade

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After upgrading RQT_GUI now fails when run:

```
turtlebot@turtleVM:~$ rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui 
WARNING: Package name "swig-wx" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits and underscores.
WARNING: Package name "swig-wx" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits and underscores.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/rqt_gui/rqt_gui", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(main.main())
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/main.py", line 57, in main
    return super(Main, self).main(argv, standalone=standalone, plugin_argument_provider=plugin_argument_provider)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/main.py", line 479, in main
    plugin_manager.discover()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_manager.py", line 108, in discover
    self._plugin_menu.add_plugin(plugin_descriptor)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_menu.py", line 79, in add_plugin
    self._enrich_action(action, action_attributes, base_path)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_menu.py", line 130, in _enrich_action
    raise UserWarning('icon "%s" not found' % str(path))
UserWarning: icon "../src/kobuki_qtestsuite/resources/images/kobuki_icon.png" not found
```

Had this happen on a couple of machines, so quite sure it's not my setup. All packages are now upgraded and nothing is held back.

Seems like the recent upgrades broke a lot of things. Is this a weird situation due to ROS changing hands, or is it unrelated to that?

I've spent a day of leave just trying to get stuff working again, and looks like I won't have my turtlebot running for MakerFaire Adelaide.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59841/rqt_gui-fails-after-upgrade/) by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 478 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's because the recent faulty release. [We're working on it](http://groups.google.com/group/ros-sig-rqt/browse_thread/thread/56866547d12c4eff?hl=en), and looks like the fix is ready to be released into public (although it might take several days. I'm not sure when is the next release date).

Quick workaround if you don't use `rqt` with `kobuki`, uninstall `kobuki` pkgs should work (so far I've only seen this issue to happen when `kobuki`s are installed). But just to be clear, the root cause is in `qt_gui_core` metapackage and `kobuki` is not doing any harm.

Sorry for any inconvenience.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) on 2013-04-03**:
Thanks, Issac. I'll keep my eyes out for the new release.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-04**:
Now the fixed version (`qt_gui_core` 0.2.15-1) is available publicly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there!

Try to edit source in the end of ~/.bashrc file. I've erase repetitive lines for sources and it worked for me.

GL!

---

Originally posted by [creation](https://answers.ros.org/users/4595/creation/) with karma: 11 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) on 2013-04-03**:
Thanks Creation, I had a check and there was a repeated setup.bash in there, but after removing it and opening a new terminal the problem is still there.